How to use a custom port with PHP Mysql PDO using user@localhost
I have to make a PDO connection using these constraints:

The mysql user I have is in format user@localhost
I need to open a connection on MaxScale, then I need a custom TCP port
I cannot use socket connection.

I tried with this DSN:
mysql:host=localhost;port=4008;dbname=mydb

But if fails because the port is ignored when host=localhost, somehow seems Mysql is forcing the socket connection when the hostname is localhost EVEN IF I set mysql:host
I tried
mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=4008;dbname=mydb

The connection works, but the user is refused due to wrong hostname.
Do I have any solution to this problem?

"omehow seems Mysql is forcing the socket connection" - that appears to be dependent on the OS rather than MySQL itself. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php: "Note: Unix only: When the host name is set to "localhost", then the connection to the server is made through a domain socket. "

"but the user is refused due to wrong hostname" - and allowing that user to also connect via the IP address instead of the host name, is not an option?
